# Sum specific columns of pandas dataframe based on if column name ends with string and begins with value in another column

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [2}: df = pd.DataFrame([['X', 2, 3, 4, 5 ,6, 7], ['Y',8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13], ['X', 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]], \
 columns=['name', 'X 1_V1', 'X 1_V2', 'Y 1_V1', 'Y 1_V2','X 2_V1', 'X 2_V2'])
In[3]: print(df)

Out[3]: name  X 1_V1  X 1_V2  Y 1_V1  Y 1_V2  X 2_V1  X 2_V2
    0    X       2       3       4       5       6       7
    1    Y       8       9      10      11      12      13
    2    X      14      15      16      17      18      19
```

I want to sum the columns that begin with the value in the 'name' column and end with 'V1'. So the 1st and 3rd row would sum the 2nd and 5th column, while the 2nd row would sum the 4th column.

```
In[3]: df['sum']
Out[3]: 
0     8
1    10
2    32
Name: sum, dtype: int64
```

I have tried

```
df["sum_Area"] = df[[x for x in df.columns if (x.split(' ')[0] == df['name']) and (x.endswith('peak_area'))]].sum(axis = "columns")
```

But receive the fault : `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` The column names are strings

[Results I would like in picture format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4DDO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['sum']=df.apply(lambda x:sum([x[c] for c in df.columns if c.split()[0]==x['name'] and c.endswith('V1')]),axis=1)
```

Comment: So this lamda function's argument is 'x' and 'x' is my dataframe? I need to read up more on this. Thank you very much it solved my issue.

Comment: here x is a row